# Face Recognition confidence going down while enrolling more person & images

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

I have face recognition project which consist of enrolling person and then training the model. Once all done, I then call the recognize script to recognize the face.

In enrollment, I am first detecting the faces using `caffe model`. I am then using open face recognizer to extract the face embedding and then saving all the face embedding in pickle file. In training, I am using rbf kernel to train.

Lets say I have below dataset of persons having 20 images each

```
1. personA
        image1.jpg
        image2.jpg
        ...
        ...
        image20.jpg

2. personB
        image1.jpg
        image2.jpg
        ...
        ...
        image20.jpg

3. personC
        image1.jpg
        image2.jpg
        ...
        ...
        image20.jpg

4. personD
        image1.jpg
        image2.jpg
        ...
        ...
        image20.jpg
```

If I pass test image of `personC`, I am getting recognition result as `personC` with confidence `92%`. Now lets if I enroll more person with lets say 30-40 images, then what I am seeing is that confidence score of personC is getting decreased to 64%, to which I am not sure why this is happening. Below is how I am training the model:

```
params = {"C": [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0], "gamma": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]}
model = GridSearchCV(SVC(kernel="rbf", gamma="auto", probability=True), params, cv=3, n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(data["embeddings"], labels)
```

in above code, `data["embeddings"]` are the face embeddings of persons and labels are the names.

So what I have noticed is that once I start adding more and more person with more amount of images, the persons having less images for them confidence starts getting low. Is this true.? Is there anyone who has experienced this type of issue.? How can I resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This makes complete sense.

If you only had one person/image in your data set and you trained your model on it, the model should get close to 100% accuracy. As the model has more faces/persons added, there is more ambiguity over which person the face belongs to.

As your data set grows, your model should be trying to generalize to the data without over-fitting. It's possible that PersonC looks similar to another person in your data set. It's also possible that your model is not the right choice, your hyper parameters are wrong, or something is not configured correctly. That part, I can't comment on.

As for a person with less images having the confidence getting lower. Is that what you are observing? Have you tried that with numerous people in your data set? You should be able to answer that question yourself by looking whether or not you have more accurate predictions.

It may also help to plot some of these images so you can see if the misclassification makes sense.

Comment: Do you mean plotting the output of model

Comment: No, I mean plotting the images using something like matplotlib (or you could just open the jpegs and look at them). The point is to understand whether or not the computer's misclassification makes sense. (i.e. is another person a twin brother or similar looking etc)

That and plotting a confusion matrix so you know which samples are confused with which.